# PHP cannot mysql_close() because resource is null?

Tags: php

I'm using a destructor to close the db connection.

```
    function __destruct(){
        var_dump($this->dblink);
        mysql_close($this->dblink);
    }
```

var dump gives me

```
resource(7) of type (mysql link) NULL
```

and the mysql_close() gives me:

```
Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** 
Thanks to the replies I found the issue. destruct is being called by another parent class. Pretty obvious to me now.

**THANKS**

Comment: Perhaps the var_dump is messing with the variable when it gets dumped?  I also note that you're getting what seems like two var_dump messages (one remarking about a resource, one showing a null).  Perhaps there are actually two objects that get `__destruct()` called in your code, in which case there is no disconnect between the messages you are receiving.  One object has a valid database link.  The second object has a null where the database link should be, and also throws a warning.

Comment: is __destruct called too late? try to unset your variable if your just relying on the script termination to call it.

Comment: @ Tchalvak Thanks for the response. Actually i slipped the vdump in because i was trying to figure out why i was getting the warning.

Comment: Are you sure the destructor is not called twice? Remember the destructor will be fired up for each instance that is destroyed.

Comment: Fair enough, so it's probably not the var_dump, but as netcoder says, there is evidence of two calls to `__destruct()` in what you've shown us.

Comment: @asdfasdf: If you found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it. Answers do not go in questions. This is not a message board.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is automatically destructed when the script is finished. The resource is freed as well. If the resource is freed before the object is destructed, you cannot close it. So, only close it if you need the connection to be closed before the script terminates. It is no use closing it when the script is already finishing. All resources are closed and cleaned up automatically.

Comment: It's clean to do so. It reduces the risk of forgetting and leaking resources. And it promotes clean programming and an overall healthier lifestyle! It's also a good idea to remain connected to the DB server for as short a time as possible: remember, it's not just PHP's resources that you should be thinking about!

Comment: It is indeed a good idea to cleanup unused resources, but you need to remember that PHP does that as well. In this case you could add extra checks to see if the resource isn't freed already, or you could add a separate `disconnect` method to free the resource as soon as you don't longer need it. In either case, you should be cautious of not freeing stuff that was freed by PHP already.

Answer (score 0):

First object must be destructed and next free up the resources to be null...Then You wont have the issue

<< mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource >>

and You cant close connection if object has already been over!